# Matlab - change height of the text field on the whole figure

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to change the height of a text field on the whole figure without changing the x and y position?

To change we must use the position, which requires to change the coordinates. I would like to change only the height, without changing x and y.

Answer (score 2):

Just store the current x and y, and use those in your `set` call like so:

```
old_pos = get(text_field_handle,'Position');
set(text_field_handle,'Position',[old_pos(1:2),new_width,new_height]);
```

Comment: That's OK for axes objects, but it doesn't work for text objects where the position is a 2 or 3 elements vector, see mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can change the `FontSize` property, this won't change the coordinates, but will increase width as well as height. See [Text Properties](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html) in the doc for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are working with `uicontrol('style','text')`.

From the [uicontrol properties](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html#Position) you have:

> *Position*
>
> ```
> position rectangle
>
> *Size and location of uicontrol*. The rectangle defined by this property 
> specifies the size and location of the control within the parent figure 
> window, uipanel, or uibuttongroup. Specify Position as:
>
> [left bottom width height]
>
> where left and bottom define the distance from the lower-left corner of the 
> container to the lower-left corner of the rectangle. width and height are the 
> dimensions of the uicontrol rectangle.
> ```

You can then just change the `width` and `height` keeping the original `left` and  `bottom`.

Comment: That's Ok for axes objects, but it doesn't work for text objects where the position is a 2 or 3 elements vector, see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html.

Comment: @am304 I assume that the OP is programming a GUI, thus using a uicontrol. I updated the link.

Comment: OK. That wasn't my understanding. I thought he was just adding some text to a plot, but maybe you're right.

Answer (score 1):

One can set the `Margin` property of a `text` object to increase the height of the object without changing the fontsize, but this influences both the height and the width of the text object. I am not sure what it means to make the height smaller than what Matlab thinks is the text height, so I will assume you are interested in increasing the size.

Increasing the height of the text object is relatively easy if you are willing to use the LaTeX interpreter. You just need to add an "empty" box of whatever height you want:

```
text(0.5, 0.25, 'Hello World\parbox{\textwidth}{\vspace{1in}}', 'Interpreter', 'LaTeX', 'BackgroundColor',[1, 0, 0]);
```

This won't increase the height by exactly 1 inch, instead it will be more like 1 inch minus a baseline skip. Determining the actual height increase in displayed units adds even more problems. You might be able to change the height with unicode characters, and hence skip the LaTeX interpreter, but I have no idea how.